# jvisualvm 1.3.2 refuses to show CPU for some local apps and not others

Tags: java, jvisualvm

OSX Lion, Java 1.6.0_33

One program running at the moment, shows CPU in jvisualvm

```
Overview:

Host: localhost
Main class: org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer
Arguments: <none>

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.6.0_33, vendor Apple Inc.
Java Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
JVM Flags: <none>
```

Another does not:

```
Host: localhost
Main class: com.basistech.ntt.SocialSecurityDeathMasterToDistribution
Arguments: /data/ssdm/SSDM.txt target/ssdm.dist.txt

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.6.0_33, vendor Apple Inc.
Java Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
JVM Flags: <none>

Heap dump on OOME: disabled
```

Why?

Comment: I can only assume that you need to command line argument added. This is not needed on windows or linux, but I can't imagine any other difference between your two programs.

Comment: What command line argument would that be? I've posted the args to the  happy program, and there are none that seem relevant.

Comment: One of the JMX permitions or authority perhaps, like I said this doesn't happen on windows or linux unless the jvisualvm is running as a different user to the process. I assume you are running everything as the same user?

Comment: I see a similar result with application bundles in which the `Info.plist` specifies `1.5*`, but not when the jnlp specifies `1.5+`. Are you using `JavaApplicationStub`?

Comment: Not at all. There are all launched with the java command, no stub.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you still have the issue, but this answer might help others

I'm on linux and had exactly the same behaviour as yours :

- local jvm cpu sampling disabled on some vm but working on others (jvisualvm itself for example)
- when the cpu sampling was not working, jvisualvm would take 5-6 min to attach to the vm

in my `/etc/hosts` file,  the 127.0.0.1 entry did not contain my hostname so i changed it from :

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

to

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 **my_host_name**

(**my_host_name** : what you get when you run the cmd : hostname).

(i tried it after reading point 5 of : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/faq.html which is not the issue i was facing, but as i was out of things to try... )

Before changing `/etc/hosts` the command : `hostname -i` returned my eth0 ip address. After it returned `127.0.0.1`

I don't really understand why, but it fixed my issue.